# Do I need to adduri for every column?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

If I have a table with the columns:

```
COMPANION_ID

COMPANION_NAME

COMPANION_TYPE
```

do I need to do

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/#",COMPANION_ID);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/*",COMPANION_NAME);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/*",COMPANION_TYPE);
```

or do I do:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/COMPANION_ID/#",COMPANION_ID);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/COMPANION_NAME/*",COMPANION_NAME);
uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/COMPANION_TYPE/*",COMPANION_TYPE);
```

Comment: do you need to query / delete / update by "name" and / or by "type"?

Comment: @pskink yes I do need to

Comment: so follow the path #2

Comment: @pskink perfect that's what I thought I just couldn't find any anwers before asking. Thank you

Comment: sure, you are welcome

Comment: @pskink do I also need path #2's version of companion_id?

Comment: yes, i think so, COMAPNION_ID is (i believe) the only column that is unique in your table so using id is the only way to get one particular row

Comment: I would use rather `companion` and `companion/#` the first would be dir uri and second item uri, for query/insert/delete/update i would use or by id with item uri for single item or with where statement and dir uri

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused about UriMatchers. Use projections to get columns in your query, use UriMatchers to differentiate paths in your content provider.

To get a companion by id i would use yourfirst uri matcher

- uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY,"COMPANION/#",COMPANION_ID);

after that i would identify each column using a **projection**:

// Queries the user dictionary and returns results
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    yourUri,   // The content URI of the COMPANION table, with your ID
    mProjection,                        // The columns to return for each row
    mSelectionClause                    // Selection criteria
    mSelectionArgs,                     // Selection criteria
    mSortOrder);                        // The sort order for the returned rows

Take a look here to clarify: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html